# asp.net mvc5 db-first data annotation model displayname

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is my model declation

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductCategoryAttr))]
[DisplayName("Product Category List")]
public partial class ProductCategory
{

}

[DisplayName("Product Category List")]
public class ProductCategoryAttr
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product Category Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show

```
Product Category List
```

in View Page

```
@model List<WebApplication4.Models.ProductCategory>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0])
```

But it didn't work...
How to do it?

Comment: Did you got an error?

Comment: Have you included properties `Id` and `Name` in your `ProductCategory` class? Assuming you have, the code you have shown works fine and will output `Product Category List`

Comment: @meJustAndrew   no error，just get [0]

Comment: @Stephen Muecke
   Yes. I can see displayname of name. Maybe there is something curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Let the **namespace** in the db-first class and data annotation class be **the same**.
It can show what I want.

Answer (score -1):

You should write your second `model` with Capital `M`

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model[0])
```

`Model` in acctually your instance of `ViewModel` which is `List<ProductCategory>` but `model` is for lambda expression and it could be anything. for example this line is also valid

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Foo => Model[0])
```